# How to check if URL is blob or a link in php

Tags: php, file, blob

How to check if a image src have a blob URL or simple URL in php

**Edit**

You can simply say that how to check if a object in img src is blob or not?

Comment: It is unclear what you ask, sorry. First: why is the "file input to a form" relevant for where a URL points to and Second: a URL points to whatever a server sees fit to respond. It might change every second. All you can do is test what comes back. If that is what you ask, then go for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it before using it in the image source.

Firstly take out the link from the line SRC using regex or using DomDocument like following:
 
    `$html = '';
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $src = $xpath->evaluate("string(//img/@src)");` 

Then use    parse_html to check if there is host and path in the url. If the    parse_html results in false then the link could be stored and check for proper files using     file_put_content .

Answer (score 0):

You can use file_exists to check if it is a file.

```
if( file_exists( $url ) ) ){
  // it is a file
} 
else{
  // it is a blob
}
```